# Is there a functional syntax in pandas for setting a value of a series based on integer location?

Tags: python, pandas, functional-programming

Say I have the series `pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2','c':3})`, and I want to edit the first value, I can call `pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}).set_value('a',0)`.

Is there a similar function that will accept the integer location instead of the index label?

I.e. I want to do this

```
s = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}).set_value(0,0)
```

Also is there way to make this not mutate the original dataframe. I guess what I want is something in the spirit of `DataFrame.assign` but that operates row-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a numeric index by setting `takeable=True`.

```
s = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}).set_value(0,0, takeable=True)
```

Comment: this is very obscure!

Answer (score 1):

`set_value` mutates your original pandas DataFrame or Series:

```
ser = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
new_ser = ser.set_value(0,0)

print(new_ser is ser)
True
```

You have to manually create a copy of it:

```
ser = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':2,'c':3})
new_ser = ser.copy()
new_ser.set_value(0,0)

print(new_ser is ser)
False
```

To set values via their index location, you can use `set_value` with takeable=True as @Batman pointed out. You may also use `iat` (*index at*) which is explicitly designed to reference values by index location:

```
 # create copy and set value via iat
 new_ser = ser.copy()
 new_ser.iat[0] = 0
```

Performance is a bit better for `set_value` in this example:

```
 %%timeit
 new_ser = ser.copy()
 new_ser.set_value(0,0, takeable=True)
 10000 loops, best of 3: 53.4 µs per loop
```

---

```
 %%timeit
 new_ser = ser.copy()
 new_ser.iat[0] = 0
 10000 loops, best of 3: 63.6 µs per loop
```